# Prove or disprove if $L_{1}$ is Turing-recognizable and $L_{2}$ is co-Turing-recognizable then $L_{1}\cap L_{2}$ is decidable

Tags: turing-machines, computability

I thought about these languages:
$$L_{1} = A_{TM} = \big\{ \langle M, w \rangle \mid M \text{ is TM and }M \text{ accepts } w \big\}$$
$$L_{2} = \overline{HALT_{TM}} = \big\{ \langle M, w \rangle \mid M \text{ is TM and }M \text{ doesn't halt on input } w \big\}$$

Their intersection:
$$L_{1}\cap L_{2}  = \big\{ \langle M, w \rangle \mid M \text{ is TM and }M \text{ accepts and doesn't halt on input } w \big\}$$

If I assume that the intersection is decidable by TM $T$ so I can use $T$ to decide $A_{TM}$ and that's a contradiction.

Is it true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is wrong. Note if $M$ accepts $w$, it must halt on $w$, so $L_1\cap L_2$ is the empty set, which is of course decidable.

To disprove the statement, you can set $L_2$ to be $\Sigma^*$, i.e. the language containing all strings. Since $\emptyset$ is Turing recognizable, $L_2$ is co-Turing recognizable. However, $L_1\cap L_2=L_1$ is undecidable.

Comment: Nitpick: we need to explicitly set $L_1$ so to be undecidable but recognizable, e.g. the halting problem. Otherwise, only knowing that $L_1$ is recognizable does not necessarily imply that it is undecidable.

Comment: @chi, right, I just described the change to the proof in OP.

Comment: I don't understand your disproving. Did you use these languages: 
$$E_{TM}  = \big\{ \langle M \rangle \mid M \text{ is TM and }L(M)= \emptyset \big\}$$
$$ALL_{TM}  = \big\{ \langle M \rangle \mid M \text{ is TM and }L(M)= \Sigma^{*} \big\}$$

What is $L_{1}$ and what is  $L_{2}$?

Comment: @Asaf $L_1=A_{TM}$, $L_2=\Sigma^*=\{s\mid s\text{ can be any string }\}$.

Comment: Why $L_{2}$ is co-Turing recognizable?
I can use automata that accepts all strings.

Comment: @Asaf co-Turing recognizable does not mean "not Turing recognizable".

Comment: Thanks. It will work for any language $L_{1}$ that is Turing-recognizable but is undecidable.